# Knockout add method to already defined model

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

Is there any way to add a new method to an already defined Model e.g.

```
var MyModel = function() {

   var self = this;
   self.method1 = function () {
     return true;
   }
   self.method2 = function () {
     return true;
   }
};


viewModel = new MyModel ();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

This gives me access to `viewModel.method1()` and `viewModel.method2()` but I want to be able to add a new method later on in the file that I can access in the same way e.g.

```
viewModel.extend = function() {
   self.method3 = function () {
     return true;
   }
}
```

And now I would have access to `viewModel.method1()`, `viewModel.method2()` and `viewModel.method3()`

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define one using a prototype:

```
MyModel.prototype.method3 = function() {
    var self = this; // Reference to instance of MyModel
    var m1 = self.method1();
    var m2 = self.method2();
    return true;
};
```

In your example:

```
var MyModel = function() {

   var self = this;
   self.method1 = function () {
     return true;
   }
   self.method2 = function () {
     return true;
   }
};


viewModel = new MyModel ();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

MyModel.prototype.method3 = function() {
    return true;
};

console.log(viewModel.method3());
```